# Como bloquear caracteres especiais vindo de um "paste"?

Tags: jquery, regex, validação

Estou com o seguinte problema, existe uma validação sendo feita dessa maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).on("paste", "#email", function(event) {
     var $obj = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            var str  = $obj.val();
              $obj.val(str.replace(/[^a-za-uA-ZA-U0-9_@\.\'\b  \t]/g, ''));
            }, 2);
   });
});
```

Quando é colado algum texto com caracteres especiais a função da um replace nos caracteres especiais por *vazio*. Existe alguma maneira de bloquear os caracteres especiais do *paste* sem utilizar o *replace*?

O meu maior problema é que o usuário consegue ver os caracteres dentro do input antes deles serem substituídos, a validação está ok, porém estou procurando alguma outra forma de maneira que o usuário não "veja" o replace acontecendo.

Comment: Mas você já não esta bloqueando eles? você bloqueou através da troca pelo vazio. O que você quer na verdade é troca-los? `[áäà] =>  a`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert , da maneira atual o usuário consegue ver os caracteres colados antes deles receberem o replace, eu queria que não fosse possivel mesmo colar algum texto com caracteres especiais

Comment: acredito que regex não seja o que você está procurando então, não existe nenhum método de regex que substitua ou bloqueie de antemão os caracteres especiais, talvez você possa implementar a atualização desse método a cada caractere digitado, assim como fazem nas formatações de cpf quando o usuario vai digitando o numero e é adicionado "." na 4ª, 8ª, 12ª posição e "-" para separar os ultimos 2 dígitos dos demais.

Comment: Tenta trocar o evento, não tem outro p/ colocar no lugar do PASTE